# Mongoid unset still shows up the field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I'm currently working on a Mongoid document. What I'm trying to do is to remove a field using `unset` method.

```
class Record
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :count,  type: Integer, default: 1
end
```

Then I created a new data:

`record = Record.new`

`record.count # returns 1 by default`

I also looked at the mongo console and the field is there.

When I do this:

`record.unset(:count)`

Accessing mongo console, the field is gone, but when I try this:

`record.inspect`

I can still see the `count` field.

I'm using mongoid 3.1.6

Comment: [`unset`](https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/blob/v3.1.6/lib/mongoid/contextual/atomic.rb#L174) is a very thin wrapper around `update_all` and that just sends a `$set` operation into MongoDB. As to why it works this, I don't know the reasoning behind it.

Answer (score 1):

Please understand that 'count' is a defined field (of interest) in your Mongoid schema for class Record,
so Mongoid will report its value when you inspect it on the client-side,
even if you have unset it on the server-side.

If you don't want to "see" the count field when inspecting client-side,
you can remove it as a defined field in your Mongoid schema,
but then you will eliminate all of the Mongoid convenience of "dot" field access and default value, e.g.,
you will have to access via record['count'], will no longer have record.count accessors,
and will have to program your own default value.

Hope that this helps to clarify things.